# iex, how to reload structs effectively?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I found a minimal example that shows one of the problem that I encounter while learning Elixir.

I write a script:

```
defmodule P do
  defstruct a: 2
  def geta(%P{a: a}), do: a
end
```

Use `iex "filename"` to start an `iex` session check that it works with `P.geta(%P{a: 42})`

Then I change the file to

```
defmodule P do
  defstruct a: 2, b: 4
  def getb(%P{a: a, b: b}), do: b
end
```

And when I launch `iex`, it fails:

```
== Compilation error on file p.ex ==
** (CompileError) p.ex:3: unknown key :b for struct P
    (elixir) src/elixir_map.erl:185: :elixir_map."-assert_struct_keys/5-lc$^0/1-0-"/5
    (elixir) src/elixir_map.erl:62: :elixir_map.translate_struct/4
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1353: :lists.mapfoldl/3

** (exit) shutdown: 1
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:202: Kernel.ParallelCompiler.handle_failure/5
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:185: Kernel.ParallelCompiler.wait_for_messages/8
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:55: Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/3
       (iex) lib/iex/helpers.ex:168: IEx.Helpers.c/2
```

I can work around it by removing the content of the file except the definition, launching iex, pasting back the content of the file and relaunching iex.
It looks to me as if the old struct is somehow **cached** by iex.

Two questions:

- Is this a bug or a design decision?
- Is there a more clever way to work around it?

Comment: You're launching a brand new `iex "filename"` after changing the file to include `:b` right? I can't reproduce this on my system.

Comment: Like @Dogbert I tried this and I can't reproduce the issue on my system.  Can you share more detailed reproduction steps?

Comment: I do that yes and I use Interactive Elixir (1.2.3) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

Comment: Perhaps a longshot, but try `r P` in your iex. If you've saved the file, it should recompile and reload the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is you have functions on your struct module. That will cause problems like your seeing. You need to separate your struct and functions. You can nest the struct module inside your module if you want to.

```
defmodule P do
  defmodule Data do
     defstruct a: 2, b: 4
  end

  def geta(%Data{a: a}), do: a
  def getb(%Data{b: b}), do: b
end
```

in iex:

```
iex> P.geta(%P.Data{a: 10})
10
iex> P.getb(%P.Data{a: 3, b: 24})
24
```